# Ng-repeat into a directive with a string & ng-repeat property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to dynamically build an encoded query in an ng-repeat that will then be passed into a typeahead directive.

I know I can pass in the entire ng-repeat item similar to this jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/yaroslavya/8YEkh/

And I know you can easily pass a string into a directive attribute.

Is there a way to do both?

Basically in the fiddle above i'd want to do something like:

```
    <div ng-repeat="image in images">            
        <typeahead-directive image='"encoded_query=" + image' ></div>
    </div>
```

I tried doing this and it works in the console, but the ng-repeat property isn't actually stored inside the directive:

```
    <div ng-repeat="image in images">            
        <typeahead-directive image='encoded_query={{image}}' ></div>
    </div>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Try image="encoded_query={{$parent.image}}" if the typeahead-directive has its own scope.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do both?

In a your directive you can get the string value of the your `image` attribute with `$attrs`.

You can use `$eval` to get the object from the your `image` attribute.

Your HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="image in images">            
      <div myimg image='image' ></div>
</div>
```

The directive

```
myModule.directive('myimg', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        template: '<p>{{image.title}}</p><img src="{{image.url}}" />',
        controller: ['$scope','$attrs', function($scope, $attrs) {
            console.log($attrs.image);
            console.log($scope.$eval($attrs.image));
        }]
        /*link:function(scope, elem, attr){
            console.log(attr.image);
            console.log(scope.$eval(attr.image));
        }*/
    };
});
```

Controller local attributes are documented in [AngularJS $compile API Reference -- controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-controller-)

The `$eval` function is documented in [AngularJS scope API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Also notice that I set `scope: false` because your directive doesn't really need a scope.